# Amazon Redshift: Undefined use of FROM keyword: DELETE table_name FROM

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

While reading through a former employee's AWS Redshift SQL queries, I came across something that simplifies down to this:

```sql
delete
    names
from
(
    select 'Stu' AS last_name 
) kill_list
where
    kill_list.last_name = names.last;
```

When I run it against Redshift, it looks like it works as if I ran:

```sql
delete from
    names
using
(
    select 'Stu' AS last_name 
) kill_list
where
    kill_list.last_name = names.last;
```

However I can't find any documentation about using the `FROM` clause after the table name that you are deleting from so I'm wondering if this is valid sql code or if it's invalid but we got lucky and Redshift evaluated it the way we wanted it to.

When I try running it here using Postgres v10, get a syntax error:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nYQz84mgNMctMiS38zk5AZ/0

Comment: I don't know Redshift, but that is definitely illegal syntax in PostgreSQL. Maye you simplified the query too much.

Comment: The derived table (kill_list sub-query) doesn't return any `ln` column, so the kill_list.ln condition isn't valid anyway.

Comment: @jarlh Ah yes, that was a typo on my part. Edited post.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe, fwiw, I ran that query against Redshift and it worked

Answer (score 2):

From [DELETE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DELETE.html):

```
DELETE [ FROM ] table_name
[ {USING } table_name, ... ]
[ WHERE condition ]
```

So, the `FROM` is optional.

Comment: Yes, but if I remove the `FROM` from that query above, the query fails on Redshift. Also, the `FROM` in that query appears after table_name, not before it.